# Any way to get the current wait time in a chat queue?

Tags: liveagent, omnichannel

I have been reading all the documentation and have yet to really find an answer to this question:

Is there any way to get the current wait time in a live agent chat queue? From what I was reading there is no way to get it with the default Live Agent enabled.

Based on [Omni-Channel Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm) it appears the AgentWork table has the information I need as it has a field called: `RequestDateTime`. Which means if I use that and the current time of everyone in a `Assigned` status. I would be able to calculate the average wait time before someone is in chat.

Now when I query the table `AgentWork` I do not get any records even though a chat is currently in queue.

What records should show up in `AgentWork`? Is there a better way I can get the wait time of chats currently in the queue?

Comment: A chat which is currently in queue does not create any AgentWork record. Record is created once the Agent see request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for completeness I'm going to answer my question. `Agentwork` only works if you are using OmniChannel for chat. LiveAgent chat will not populate `Agentwork` object.

Now one thing to call out there is a nasty bug currently in Salesforce that if the Chat is transferred to another agent. What happens is the `RequestDateTime` field is null Salesforce treats this as a 0 for a date/time field which they store as a Epoch. Which then gives you `SpeedToAnswer` of 47 years. As they calculate it the following way `AcceptDatetime` - `RequestDateTime` = `SpeedToAnswer`.

More information can be found [here.](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5kSAAS) So I added a condition in my where clause to throw away anything with a greater then 10000 seconds wait time (Which should never happen in my Company Anyway).

```
Public String generateWaitTimeMessage(string queueToQuery)
{
    Final Integer MINS_TO_QUERY = -60;
    DateTime currentTime = system.now();
    DateTime currentTimeOffset = currentTime.addMinutes(MINS_TO_QUERY);
    List<AgentWork> agentWorkList = [SELECT id, SpeedToAnswer, OriginalQueue.DeveloperName, createddate 
                                     FROM AgentWork
                                     WHERE OriginalQueue.DeveloperName = :queueToQuery
                                     AND createddate > :currentTimeOffset
                                     AND SpeedToAnswer != NULL
                                     AND SpeedToAnswer < 10000
                                     ORDER BY createddate desc
                                     LIMIT 10];

    Integer count = 0;
    Integer waitTimeTotal = 0;
    for(AgentWork aw : agentWorkList)
    {
        waitTimeTotal += aw.SpeedToAnswer;
        count++;
    }

    Integer avgWaitTime = 0;
    if( count > 0 )
    {
        avgWaitTime = waitTimeTotal/count;
    }
    Integer minutes = avgWaitTime / 60;
    Integer seconds = math.mod(avgWaitTime,60);

    String newTimeMessage = 'Chat is Currently Open';
    if(avgWaitTime > 30) 
    {
        String second = 'seconds';
        String minute = 'minutes';
        if(minutes == 1) minute = 'minute';
        if(seconds == 1) second = 'second';
        if(avgWaitTime >= 60)
        {
            newTimeMessage = 'An agent should be available in '+minutes+' '+minute+' and '+seconds+' '+second+'.';
        }
        else
        {
            newTimeMessage = 'An agent should be available in '+seconds+' '+second+'.';
        }
    }
    return newTimeMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way directly from Salesforce to give a wait time. You could implement a custom VisualForce page and use the [liveAgent:clientChatQueuePosition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_customizing_chat_windows_visualforce_components.htm) component, along with historical data from your org to see what the average wait time for a chat is. So number of users ahead + average wait time per user = current wait time in queue. But there is no built in way from Salesforce to accomplish that.